# How to get two different random samples from one range

Tags: python, random, range

I want to get get two different random samples from one range in python.
I tried something like this:

```
rd1 = random.sample(range(0, 10), 5) 
rd2 = random.sample(range(0, 10), 5)
print(rd1)
print(rd2)
```

Output:

```
[2, 4, 7, 6, 8]
[2, 4, 0, 7, 5]
```

But i want `rd1` and `rd2` to have no common elements like:

```
[1, 3, 9, 6, 8]
[2, 4, 0, 7, 5]
```

or

```
[0, 2, 9, 6, 1]
[3, 4, 8, 7, 5]
```

Comment: Can you generate one random range of twice the length, then split it in half?

Comment: generate one list to pull the samples from, then pull all the samples from it in one list, then split the list into two. Funny.. we both had the same idea.

Comment: Or.. `li = list(range(10)); random.shuffle(li); rd1 = li[:5]; rd2 = li[-5:]`

Answer (score 3):

random takes an iterable  so generate the first list and then do a small filtering to exclude the items from the first random list  :

```
import random
rd1  = random.sample(range(0, 10), 5)

rd2  = random.sample([i for i in range(0, 10) if i not in rd1], 5)

print(rd1)
print(rd2)
```

Output:

```
[2, 6, 9, 5, 0]
[4, 1, 3, 8, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

Get one sample of twice the length, then split it in half, something like this:

```
rd = random.sample(range(0, 10), 10)
rd1, rd2 = rd[:5], rd[5:]
print(rd1)
print(rd2)
```

Example output:

```
[5, 7, 1, 6, 3]
[2, 9, 4, 8, 0]
```

BTW you could also use `random.shuffle` to get `rd`:

```
rd = list(range(0, 10))
random.shuffle(rd)
```